# Арбитраж "round-robin"

Tags: запрос, приоритет

В кроссбаре, если несколько Master одновременно делают запрос одному Slave, должен быть арбитраж по принципу "round-robin".
Википедия показала такую картинку:

[image: round robin в вики]

Но здесь одновременно подаются запросы от "соседних" устройств. Мне непонятно, как разрешать ситуацию, например, такую:

[image: пока устр-во 3 ожидает, устр-во 2 также делает запрос]

№1 и №3 одновременно делают запрос, выполняется запрос от №1 (зеленый), а №3 ждет (серый). Спустя время врывается №2 тоже "только спросить".
Чей запрос будет выполняться следующим?